# Collection response

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

```
{#186 ▼
  +"results": Collection {#203 ▼
    #items: array:15 [▼
      0 => {#218 ▼
        +"wrapperType": "track"
        +"kind": "song"
        +"artistId": 32940
        +"collectionId": 159292399
        +"trackId": 159293848
        +"artistName": "Michael Jackson"
        +"collectionName": "The Essential Michael Jackson"
        +"trackName": "Billie Jean"
        +"collectionCensoredName": "The Essential Michael Jackson"
        +"trackCensoredName": "Billie Jean (Single Version)"
        +"artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/michael-jackson/id32940?uo=4"
        +"collectionViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/billie-jean-single-version/id159292399?i=159293848&uo=4"
        +"trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/billie-jean-single-version/id159292399?i=159293848&uo=4"
        +"previewUrl": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview122/v4/c6/50/11/c6501132-e865-3711-175a-ddb79114e42f/mzaf_3806132797788612279.plus.aac ▶"
        +"artworkUrl30": "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music127/v4/8a/65/be/8a65bef2-f23d-e43d-9124-f5e4293513f7/source/30x30bb.jpg"
        +"artworkUrl60": "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music127/v4/8a/65/be/8a65bef2-f23d-e43d-9124-f5e4293513f7/source/60x60bb.jpg"
        +"artworkUrl100": "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music127/v4/8a/65/be/8a65bef2-f23d-e43d-9124-f5e4293513f7/source/100x100bb.jpg"
        +"collectionPrice": 16.99
        +"trackPrice": 1.29
        +"trackNumber": 16
        +"trackTimeMillis": 294601
        +"country": "USA"
        +"currency": "USD"
        +"primaryGenreName": "Pop"
        +"isStreamable": true
      }
      1 => {#217 ▶}
      2 => {#216 ▶}
      3 => {#215 ▶}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with a one-liner:

```
$total = $response->results->sum('trackTimeMillis');
```

Comment: I want to get trackTimerMilis for 15 other arrays aswell

Comment: The `sum` method will sum the `trackTimerMillis` value for each of the items in the collection. Take a look at the `sum` method of `Illuminate\Support\Collection - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sum

Comment: Oh you want to both sum and retrieve each of them?

Comment: from each of the arrays that I got I want to sum the column trackTimerMillis so I get the total of them

Comment: Yes, so what i wrote is correct. If you read the laravel documentation you will see that the `sum` method will sum all the items in the collection, and if you specify a key as parameter, `sum` will return the sum of all the `trackTimerMillis` in ALL the arrays and return back the total

Comment: any idea how to get the time for each track and the collectionName to display them on a table

Comment: `$collectionTime = $response->results->pluck('trackTimerMillis', 'collectionName')->all()` will return an associative array with `collectionName` as key and `trackTimerMillis` as value

Comment: Just see the laravel collection docs to know how to operate with collections - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

Comment: Then if the answer solved your problem please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple iterable object, there's nothing special or Laravel related about this.

You can just do:

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($response['results']->items as $item) {
    $sum += $item->trackTimeMillis;
}

var_dump($sum);
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Sorry, I have misread the Collection. Try again with the updated code.